# Dynamic grouping and hirearchical results in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to produce Hierarchical summary in sql.

The user will send the columns to group by as parameters to the stored procedure ,so group by is dynamic

```
For eg. User will send to group records by DeptNo and then by Job columns
```

I need to produce the result as below
[Final output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIrir.jpg)

The individual query for group by deptno

```
Select d.DEPTNO,Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, Sum(Sal) Total from Emp e inner join Dept d
on e.DEPTNO=d.DEPTNO GROUP BY  d.DEPTNO;
```

The query for group by DEPTNO,Job

```
select  Deptno, Job, Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, Sum(Sal) Total from emp group by DEPTNO,Job  order by deptno
```

[DeptnobyJob](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGgbU.jpg)

Currently the query i used to produce the result is as below

```
 select  Deptno, Job,
    Count(EmpNo) EmpCount, 
    Sum(Sal) Total
     from emp group by DEPTNO,Job   with rollup order by Deptno, EmpCount desc
```

Is there any other better option to get summary results.
It is to display in mvc web and no ssrs

Comment: I like the `with rollup` solution. Is it working fine?

Comment: You should avoid `WITH ROLLUP`.  It has been depreciated and will be removed from a future version of SQL Server ([Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)).  Instead use [GROUPING SETS](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510427(v=sql.105).aspx).

Comment: @destination-data: Wow, didn't know that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution to `GROUPING SETS` and with `Rollup`is Dynamic SQL. Build up a query string and execute it using `Execute`. If anyone one wants to try, Do something like this:

```
declare @Query nvarchar(max) = 'select column1,column2,Column3, Count(*) from table1 group by ' + @param1 + ',' + @param2 + ',' + @param3;

Execute(@Query)
```

you can build a dynamic query according to your liking using your parmeters and then execute it to get the desired results. Be ware of SQL Injection Though!